# Why do some webservers complain about memory leaks they create?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, webserver, thread-local

The title might be a bit strong, but let me explain how I understand what happens. I guess this happened with Tomcat (and the message cited comes from Tomcat), but I'm not sure anymore.

*TL;DR At the bottom there's a summary why I'm claiming that it is the web servers' fault.*

I might be wrong (but without the possibility of being wrong there would be no reason to ask):

- An application uses a library
- the library uses a `ThreadLocal`
- the `ThreadLocal` refers to an object from the library
- each object refers to its `ClassLoader`

The webserver

- pools its worker threads for efficiency
- lends an arbitrary thread to an application
- does nothing special (w.r.t. the thread pool) when an application stops or redeploys

If I understand it correctly, after a redeploy the old "dirty" threads continue to be reused. Their `ThreadLocal`s refer to the old classes which refer to their `ClassLoader` which refer to the whole old class hierarchy. So a lot of stuff stays in the `PermGen` space which over time leads to an `OutOfMemoryError`. *Is this right so far?*

---

I'm assuming two things:

- the [redeploy frequency](http://famulatus.com/ks/item/305-java-ee-productivity-report-2011-redeploy-frequency.html) is a few time per hour
- the [thread creation overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117072/java-thread-creation-overhead) is a fraction of a millisecond

So a complete thread pool renewal upon each redeploy costs a fraction of a millisecond a few times per hour, i.e., there's a time overhead of `0.0001 * 12/3600 * 100%` i.e. `0.000033%`.

But instead of accepting this tiny overhead, there are [countless problems](https://www.google.com/#q=java+web+server+memory+leak). *Is my calculation wrong or what am I overlooking?*

---

As a warning we get the message

> The web application ... created a ThreadLocal with key of type ... and a value of type ... but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped.

which should be better stated as

> The web server ... uses a thread pool but failed to renew it after stopping (or redeploying) an application.

Or am I wrong? The time overhead is negligible even when all threads get recreated from time to time. But clearing their `ThreadLocal`s before they are provided to the applications would suffice and be even faster.

#### Summary

*There are some real problems (recently [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642687/how-to-workaround-guava-memory-leak)) and the user can do nothing about it. The library writers sometimes can and sometimes can not. IMHO the web servers could solve it pretty easily.* The thing happens and has a cause. So I'm blaming the only one party which could do anything about it.

#### Proposal for what the web server should exactly do

The title of this question is more provocative than correct, but it has its point. And so does the answer by raphw. This [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642687/how-to-workaround-guava-memory-leak) has another open bounty.

I think the web servers could solve it as follows:

- ensure that each thread gets reused (or killed) sometime
- store a `LastCleanupTimestamp` in a `ThreadLocal` (for new threads it's the creation time)
- when re-using a thread, check if the cleanup timestamp is below some threshold (e.g., now minus some `delta`, e.g., 1 hour)
- if so, clean all `ThreadLocal`s and set a new `LastCleanupTimestamp`

This would assure that no such leak exists longer than `delta` plus the duration of the longest request plus the thread turnaround time.  The cost would compose as follows:

- checking a single `ThreadLocal` (i.e., some nanoseconds) per request
- cleaning all `ThreadLocal`s reflectively (i.e., some more nanoseconds once each `delta` per thread)
- the cost from removing the data possibly useful for the application which stored them. This can't break an application as no application can assume to see a thread containing the thread locals it has set (since it can't even assume to see the thread itself anymore), but it may cost time needed to recreate the data (e.g., a cached `DateFormat` instance if someone still uses such a terrible thing).

It could be switched off by simply setting the thresold, if no app has been undeployed or redeployed recently.

Comment: Is this question about all web servers or one in particular? Down voted because this sounds more like a gripe than a real question. If it is a real question it appears to be off topic.

Comment: @axiopisty: *Off topic of what?* IIRC, the message is from Tomcat, and a lot of problems are linked (some long time ago it was a problem of mine, too).

Comment: The question seems more like a gripe than it does a question. It is unclear what the question is to be answered. Are you looking for an answer that says yes, you're right, tomcat shouldn't do that. Or yes, you're right, submit a bug to tomcat? What problem are you trying to fix? It seems this should be asked on the tomcat developer mailing list instead.

Comment: As far as the error messages, you're absolutely wrong. "Failed to renew" is meaningless while "Failed to remove" is clear. "After a redeploy" is meaningless while "when the web application was stopped" is clear. (1) You aren't always redeploying when stopping an application. (2) If you are just stopping there is no renewing intended, only removing.

Comment: @axiopisty According to the comment by developerwjk, the answer looks like I'm wrong. I recall a problem exactly related to what I described, but the current problem cause might be something else.

Comment: On a side note, love the question title.

Comment: @GGrec: So do I, but many others seem to disagree. But it's true...

Comment: @developerwjk: How "absolutely wrong"? There's a global thread pool shared by all applications, right? By renewing the pool I mean removing all threads and creating new ones (possibly later). Actually, cleaning the thread-locals would do.

Answer (score 7):

*TL;DR It's not web servers that create memory leaks. It's you.*

Let me first state the problem more explicitly: `ThreadLocal` variables often refer to an instance of a `Class` that was loaded by a `ClassLoader` that was meant to be exclusively used by a container's application. When this application gets undeployed, the `ThreadLocal` reference gets orphaned. Since each instance keeps a reference to its `Class` and since each `Class` keeps a reference to its `ClassLoader` and since each `ClassLoader` keeps a reference to all classes it ever loaded, the entire class tree of the undeployed application cannot get garbage collected and the JVM instance suffers a [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java?rq=1).

Looking at this problem, you can optimize for either:

- Allow as many requests per second as possible even throughout a redeploy (thus keep response time short and reuse threads from a thread pool)
- Make sure that threads stay *clean* by discarding threads once they were *used* when a redeploy occurred (thus patch forgotten manual cleaning)

Most developers of web applications would argue that the first is more important since the second can be achieved by writing good code. And what would happen when a redeploy would happen concurrently to long lasting requests? You cannot shut down the *old* thread pool since this would interrupt running requests. (There is no globally defined maximum for how long a request cycle can take.) In the end, you would need a quite complex protocol for that and that would bring its own problems.

The `ThreadLocal` induced leak can however be avoided by always writing:

```
myThreadLocal.set( ... );
try {
  // Do something here.
} finally {
  myThreadLocal.remove();
}
```

That way, your thread will always turn out *clean*. (On a side note, this is almost like creating *global variables*: It is almost always a terrible idea. There are some web frameworks like for example Wicket that make a lot of use of this. Web frameworks like this are terrible to use when you need to do things concurrently and get very unintuitive for others to use. There is a trend away from the typical Java *one thread per request* model such as demonstrated with Play and Netty. Do not get stuck with this anti-pattern. Do use `ThreadLocal` sparingly! It is almost always a sign of bad design.)

You should further be aware that memory leaks that are induced by `ThreadLocal` are not always detected. Memory leaks are detected by scanning the web server's worker thread pool for `ThreadLocal` variables. If a `ThreadLocal` variable was found the variable's `Class` reveals its `ClassLoader`. If this `ClassLoader` or one of its parents is that of the web application that just got undeployed, the web server can safely assume a memory leak.

However, imagine that you stored some large array of `String`s in a `ThreadLocal` variable. How can the web server assume that this array belongs to your application? The `String.class` was of course loaded with the JVM's bootstrap `ClassLoader` instance and cannot be associated with a particular web application. By removing the array, the web server might break some other application that is running in the same container. By not removing it, the web server might leak a large amount of memory. (This time, it is not a `ClassLoader` and its `Class`es that are leaked. Depending on the size of the array, this leak might however even be worse.)

And it gets worse. This time, imagine that you stored an `ArrayList` in your `ThreadLocal` variable. The `ArrayList` is part of the Java standard library and therefore loaded with the system `ClassLoader`. Again, there is no way of telling that the instance belongs to a particular web application. However, this time your `ClassLoader` and all its `Classes` will leak as well as all instances of such classes that are stored in the thread local `ArrayList`. This time, the web server even cannot certainly determine that a memory leak occurred when it finds that the `ClassLoader` was not garbage collected since garbage collection can only be recommended to a JVM (via `System#gc()`) but not enforced.

**Renewing the thread pool is not as cheap as you might assume.**

A web application cannot just go and throw away all threads in a thread pool whenever an application is undeployed. What if you stored some values in those threads? When a web application recycles a thread, it should (I am not sure if all web servers do this) find all non-leaking thread local variables and reregister them in the replaced `Thread`. The numbers you stated about efficiency would therefore not longer hold.

At the same time, the web server need to implement some logic that manages the replacement of all thread pool's `Thread`s what does neither work in favor of your proposed time calculation. (You might have to deal with long lasting requests - think of running an FTP server in a servlet container -- such that this thread pool transition logic might be active for quite a long time.)

**Furthermore, `ThreadLocal` is not the only possibility of creating a memory leak in a servlet container.**

Setting a shut down hook is another example. (And it is unfortunately a common one. Here, you should manually remove the shut down hook when your application is undeployed. This problem would not be solved by discarding threads.) Shut down hooks are furthermore instances of custom subclasses of `Thread` that were always loaded by an application's class loader.

In general, any application that keeps a reference to an object that was loaded by a child class loader might create a memory leak. (This is generally possible via `Thread#getContextClassLoader()`.) In the end, it is the developer's resposibility to not cause memory leaks, even in Java applications where many developer's misinterpret the automatic garbage collection as *there are no memory leaks*. (Think of Jochua Bloch's [famous stack implementation example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843799/why-does-this-code-sample-produce-a-memory-leak).)

**After this general statement, I want to comment on Tomcat's memory leak protection:**

Tomcat does [**not** promise you to detect all memory leaks](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) but covers specific types of such leaks as they are listed in their wiki. What Tomcat actually does:

> Each Thread in the JVM is examined, and the internal structures of the
>   Thread and ThreadLocal classes are introspected to see if either the
>   ThreadLocal instance or the value bound to it were loaded by the
>   WebAppClassLoader of the application being stopped.

Some versions of Tomcat even try to compensate for the leak:

> Tomcat 6.0.24 to 6.0.26 modify internal structures of the JDK
>   (ThreadLocalMap) to remove the reference to the ThreadLocal instance,
>   but this is unsafe (see #48895) so that it became optional and
>   disabled by default from 6.0.27. Starting **with Tomcat 7.0.6, the
>   threads of the pool are renewed so that the leak is safely fixed**.

However, you have to properly configure Tomcat to do so. The wiki entry on its memory leak protection even warns you how you can break other applications when `TimerThread`s are involved or how you might leak memory leaks when starting your own `Thread`s or `ThreadPoolExecutor`s or when using common dependencies for several web applications.

All the clean up work offered by Tomcat is **a last resort**! Its nothing you want to have in your production code.

**Summarized**: It is not Tomcat that creates a memory leak, it is your code. Some versions of Tomcat try to compensate for such leaks which are detectable if it is configured to do so. However, it is your responsibility to take care of memory leaks and you should see Tomcat's warnings as an invitation to fix your code rather than to reconfigure Tomcat to clean up your mess. If Tomcat detects memory leaks in your application, there might even be more. So take a heap and thread dump out of your application and [find out where your code is leaking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

Comment: I'm confused w.r.t. "long lasting requests". As long as the requests run, there's (nearly always) some object belonging to the application using the thread local, so it's class loader is kept in memory anyway.

Comment: Imagine a servlet container with applications *A* and *B*. I redeploy application *B* while application *A* sends a 50 GB file on an FTP session which is for efficiency reason bundled in a single request cycle. (This will take a while.) Application *B* is however be redeployed now. When will I exchange the thread pool? Now? When the request cycle is over? Should I refuse new requests to *A* until the thread pool is redeployed in order to avoid new long lasting requests? This is a complex problem to solve.

Comment: Just don't reuse any threads from the old application version (or do it only under peak last). Do not wait until the whole pool is redeployed, this makes no sense. *Just consider all threads touched by the old application version as non-recyclable.* Don't care about the long running request, as there's nothing to do before it finishes.

Comment: Then you need to keep track of which thread was used to handle requests for which application. This would cause additional time and resources. Web servers are build for highest possible efficiency with possibly thousands of requests and this kind of thread managent contradicts this aim. No matter how you put it, the problem is that your application code is broken, not that the servlet container should recycle its request handler threads. However, if you require such clean up, you could of course add a custom thread handler to Tomcat. I would not recommend it, though.

Comment: But your try-finally solution for thread locals does not apply to libraries. They need the TL as long as they get used and there's no place for the `finally` clause.

Comment: You must apply the `ThreadLocal` to every request anyways. You could for example add a servlet filter that adds the variable, executes the `doFilter` on the `FilterChain` in a `try` block and releases the `ThreadLocal` variable in the `finally` block.

Comment: No. There's usually no `myThreadLocal.set(...)`, just `ThreadLocal.initialValue`. Doing anything with it in each request would either just waste time as you don't use it at all or fight the very reason why the TL was created. See [this example](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/Striped64.java?revision=1.7) of "broken code" by Doug Lea. ;)

Comment: A Java standard library class might want to keep values in a thread local class for the lifetime of an application. It can assume to be loaded by a specific class loader but your class cannot.

Comment: You're surely right that [the standard library can do more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quod_licet_Iovi,_non_licet_bovi), but TL is used by many other libraries and there are [real problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642687/how-to-workaround-guava-memory-leak) which can't be avoided by the user and sometime can't be avoided by the library writers. Your answer makes sense, but there's no definite solution.

Comment: I updated my answer after consulting some further external resources. I hope my opinion is more clear now.